# Google HTML Service: write values from multiple selects in form to spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script

I've been banging my head against this for the past several days and have finally broken down and admitted defeat.  This is my **first** project utilizing Google HTML Service, and what I'm trying to do seems simple, but I can't get it to work.  Here is what I want to happen...

1. User interacts with spreadsheet and needs to add additional rows with data
2. User selects an option from a custom menu item (got this working)
3. This selection launches an HTML service form (got this working)
4. User selects the values from two drop down lists and clicks submit
5. The selected options read read (working kind of...) and passed to the .js (**this is where I'm stuck**), which will create the rows and place the data.

Below is my code:

**Function that launches the HTML Service**

```
    function AddAdditionalApplicant() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
  ss.show(html);
}
```

**index.html**

```
<form name="AddApplicant" onsubmit="formSubmit()">

<p><b>What Type?</b></p>
    <select name="NumOfApp" id="NumOfApp">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="Cosigner">Cosigner</option>
    </select>

<p><b>How Many?</b></p>
    <select name="TypeOfApp" id="TypeOfApp">
      <option value="Roommate">Roommate</option>
      <option value="Cosigner">Cosigner</option>
    </select>

<p></p>
<div>
  <!--<input type="submit" class="button redButton" value="Submit" onclick="formSubmit()">-->
  <input type="submit" class="button redButton" value="Submit">
</div>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function formSubmit() {

//var a=document.getElementById('NumOfApp').selectedIndex;
//var b=document.getElementById('NumOfApp').options;
//alert("Index: " + b[a].index + " is " + b[a].text);

//var x=document.getElementById('TypeOfApp').selectedIndex;
//var y=document.getElementById('TypeOfApp').options;
//alert("Index: " + y[x].index + " is " + y[x].text);

    google.script.run.getValuesFromForm(document.forms[0]);
}
</script>
```

If you uncomment the lines that are commented out you will see that the values are read correctly.  Now, here is where it fails... I attempt to pass the form as an object to the function "getValuesFromFrom" using

```
google.script.run.getValuesFromForm(document.forms[0]);
```

**Function getValuesFromFrom**

```
function getValuesFromForm(AppForm){

Browser.msgbox("success")  /attempt to test and see if the execution gets this far...no go
//var a=AppForm['NumOfApp'].selectedIndex;
//var b=AppForm['NumOfApp'].options;
//Logger.log(b[a])
//
//var x=AppForm.TypeOfApp.selectedIndex;
var type = AppForm.TypeOfApp.options[AppForm.TypeOfApp.selectedIndex].value;
Logger.log(type)

}
```

Nothing happens... the browser msgBox does not pop up.  What am I missing?  Also, how can I get the form to close automatically when the "Submit" button is pressed.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
After going back and forth with @Sandy Good I realized the "AppForm" variable in the getValuesFromForm function was undefined, which means that the form object was not being passed to the function from the html.  I tried another approach, and just attempted to pass a string variable to the function by altering the script portion of the html code like this

```
var x=document.getElementById('TypeOfApp').selectedIndex;
var y=document.getElementById('TypeOfApp').options;
//alert("Index: " + y[x].index + " is " + y[x].text);
var type=y[x].value
//    google.script.run.getValuesFromForm(y[x], b[a]);
  google.script.run.withFailureHandler(google.script.host.close)
    .getValuesFromForm(type);
```

This was successful, while this...

```
var x=document.getElementById('TypeOfApp').selectedIndex;
var y=document.getElementById('TypeOfApp').options;
//alert("Index: " + y[x].index + " is " + y[x].text);
var type=y[x]
//    google.script.run.getValuesFromForm(y[x], b[a]);
  google.script.run.withFailureHandler(google.script.host.close)
    .getValuesFromForm(type);
```

was not!

So the question remains, what was I doing wrong previously?

**EDIT: July 10th...Working code**

**Function that launches the HTML Service**

```
    function AddAdditionalApplicant() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
  ss.show(html);
}
```

**index.html**

```
<form name="AddApplicant" onsubmit="formSubmit(this)">

<p><b>How Many?</b></p>
    <select name="NumOfApp" id="NumOfApp">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>

<p><b>What Type?</b></p>
    <select name="TypeOfApp" id="TypeOfApp">
      <option value="Roommate">Roommate</option>
      <option value="Cosigner">Cosigner</option>
    </select>

<p></p>
<div>
  <!--<input type="submit" class="button redButton" value="Submit" onclick="formSubmit()">-->
  <input type="submit" class="button redButton" value="Submit">
</div>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function formSubmit(argTheFormElement) {

  google.script.run
    .withFailureHandler(myFailureFunction)
    .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
    .getValuesFromForm(argTheFormElement);

}
function myFailureFunction(argError) {
  alert("There was an error: " + argError.message);
  google.script.host.close();
  }

</script>
```

**Function that receives the Form element**

```
function getValuesFromForm(AppFormElement){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
var sname = s.getName();

var num = AppFormElement.NumOfApp
var type =  AppFormElement.TypeOfApp

var activeRow = s.getActiveCell().getRow();
var addCell = s.getRange(activeRow,2);

  if (type == "Roommate") {
  for(var i = 0; i < num; ++i){
    AddRoommate(activeRow,addCell,sname,s);
    }
  }else if (type == "Cosigner"){
  for(var i = 0; i < num; ++i){
    AddCosigner(activeRow,addCell,sname,s);
    }
  }
  s.setActiveRange(addCell.offset(1,1));
}
```

Hope this helps someone out!!!

Comment: Instead of using `Browser.msgbox()` to test for the function running, try using `Logger.log("it ran!");`  Run the code, and then in the VIEW menu, look at the LOGS.  In your browser, hit the f12 key, and the browser console should be displayed.  If there is an error in the HTML, there should be an error msg.

Comment: I changed the test as you suggested and when I ran the function I did see the log entry, but only the first `Logger.log(type)` did not show anything.  When I opened the browser console this error pops when I hid submit..`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property "(class)@16f28274" from undefined.`  Which I'm guessing is caused by the following line of code: `var type = AppForm.TypeOfApp.options[AppForm.TypeOfApp.selectedIndex].value;`

Comment: You should have a `withFailureHandler` chained to the `google.script.run` code.  I doubt that the uncaught TypeError is coming from server side code.  I'm guessing it's client side code, HTML or a SCRIPT tag error.  But commenting out that line, will tell you if that's the source of the error or not.

Comment: Put the `function formSubmit() {` function into the browsers window object:  `window.formSubmit = function() {`.  Then add a `debugger;` line right at the top:  `window.formSubmit = function() { debugger;`  In chrome, the code should halt in the browser at that line, then you can execute each line one at a time and observe the variable values.

Comment: I commented out those lines, and changed the last line of the script to the following is this what you were talking about?  `  google.script.run.withFailureHandler(google.script.host.close)
    .getValuesFromForm(document.forms[0]);`  Doing so removed the error and I still see a "successful" log entry, so I uncommented the lines I commented out and submitted the form again...the form disappeared, but the execution transcript had this line...`Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot read property "(class)@1633227c" from undefined. (line 16, file "Add Application") [0.004 seconds total runtime]`

Comment: This is line 16: `var type = AppForm.TypeOfApp.options[AppForm.TypeOfApp.selectedIndex].value;`  So how exactly do I bring the value of the selected option over?

Comment: See updated answer.  Don't put `google.script.host.close` into the `withFailureHandler`.  The `withFailureHandler(myFailureFunction)` needs it's own function to branch to if an error comes back from the server.  `function myFailureFunction(argError) {console.log("There was an error: " + argError.message);}`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your form tag, and add `this` to the function:

```
onsubmit="formSubmit(this)"
```

Then modify your function:

```
function formSubmit(argTheFormElement) {
```

Then put the variable `argTheFormElement` into the google.script.run.function(parameter);

```
google.script.run.getValuesFromForm(argTheFormElement);
```

That will pass all input values to the server.  The get the values out, you must use the name of the `name` tag.

```
var type = AppForm.NumOfApp; //Get NumOfApp value
```

To make the dialog close, use:

```
google.script.host.close;
```

[google.script.host.close](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/host#close())

Comment: thanks for pointing out the single slash...I didn't have that in the original script and added it for the stack post.   As for closing the dialog do I add the code you suggested right after this line: google.script.run.getValuesFromForm(document.forms[0]);

Comment: Yes. Put the `google.script.host.close` line at the very end.

Comment: thanks for sticking with me!!!  Everything you've suggested has worked except that the form remains open...I see no errors in the execution transcript, no errors in console, but the form remains open.  This is what I have for the last few lines of the script portion `google.script.run.withFailureHandler(myFailureFunction)
    .getValuesFromForm(argTheFormElement);
  google.script.host.close
}
function myFailureFunction(argError) {console.log("There was an error: " + argError.message);}; `  Is this correct?  If so why won't the form close?